# Invalid/Foreign characters in value fetched from registry

Tags: winapi, registry, installshield

I have an installer created using Installshield 2012 that depends greatly on the value of a Registry key written by some other application developed in-house.
I use RegDBGetKeyValueEx Installscript API to fetch the value.

This value is a directory path guaranteed to have a trailing backslash.
This value serves as the TARGETDIR for my installer.

The issue is that I often see a foreign character (Chinese, Japanese or Korean) appended to the backslash.This causes my TARGETDIR to contain the foreign character. This pollutes my installation.

I feel this is some bug with Installscript API which wrongly translates the Registry value.

Please provide some inputs so that I may find the root-cause of the issue.

**EDIT 1:**

The other application in question is a purely ANSI application with no support for Unicode. There is no #define UNICODE specified anywhere. I also checked the compiler parameters and found nothing related to Unicode specified.

This application reads one Registry key and appends a backslash and updates other keys. Once this operation is done my installer fetches the values written:

```
if ((RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, csVersKey, 0, KEY_READ|KEY_WRITE, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS) &&
        (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "BasePath", NULL, NULL, (unsigned char *)szTemp, &BufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS))
    {
        m_reqPath = szTemp;
        if (m_regPath.Right(1) != "\\") m_reqPath += "\\";
        m_reqMachinePath = m_reqPath + "\\" + m_reqMachine + "\\";
        m_reqHardwarePath = m_reqMachinePath + HARDWARE_DIRECTORY;
        m_reqManualPath = m_reqMachinePath + MANUAL_DIRECTORY;
        m_reqVersionPath = m_reqMachinePath + m_reqVersion + "\\";
        m_reqFirmwarePath = m_reqVersionPath + FIRMWARE_DIRECTORY;
        m_RegVersDirectory = m_reqVersionPath + PROGRAM_DIRECTORY;
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
```

The values updated in the above code are then written to registry.
The Installscript code that fetches these values is:

```
if ((RegDBKeyExist(szBaseKey ^ szRegKey) = 1) && (RegDBGetKeyValueEx(szBaseKey ^ szRegKey, "ReqPath", nTemp, szTemp, nvSize) = 0)) then
```

**EDIT 2:**

The way the registry value is set seems to be wrong:

```
RegSetValueEx(hKey, LEICA_PATH, 0, REG_SZ, (const unsigned char*)m_reqLeicaPath.GetBuffer(m_reqLeicaPath.GetLength()), m_reqLeicaPath.GetLength());
```

I feel the correct code should have been:

```
RegSetValueEx(hKey, LEICA_PATH, 0, REG_SZ, (const unsigned char*)m_reqLeicaPath.GetBuffer(m_reqLeicaPath.GetLength()), m_reqLeicaPath.GetLength() + 1);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the value of the Registry key written by the other in house application is correct ? I remember I had once problems with RegSetValueEx function when I wrote a string by specifying the string length and not the string length + 1 for the cbData parameter.

Comment: If you look in the Registry, do you see the foreign character? If not, then you are likely reading/interpreting the value wrong in your code. Can you show your actual reading code?

Comment: Why are you requesting `KEY_WRITE` access when you are not actually writing anything to the key? Use `KEY_READ` by itself, or even just `KEY_QUERY_VALUE`. The fewer permissions you ask for, the better your chances of opening the key in stricter-security environments.  Also, you are leaking the key handle if `RegOpenKeyEx()` succeeds but `RegQueryValueEx()` fails.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:This is not my code. I am being troubled by it. Once I figure out the root cause for my trouble, I surely willfix these issues too!

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Your pointer took me to the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assigning the Registry data to your `m_reqPath` variable, you are treating it as null-terminated character data.  However, string data read by `RegQueryValueEx()` is **not** guaranteed to be null-terminated, if the original writer of the data did not include one.  This is clearly stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911.aspx).

Chances are that the string data you are reading from the Registry is **not** null-terminated, so you end up copying random data from the end of your buffer.  To account for that possibility, you need to allocate extra space in your buffer and put your own null terminator at the end of whatever data you actually read.  If the data is properly null terminated, then your terminator will simply be redundant.

You are also leaking the opened Registry key handle if `RegOpenKeyEx()` succeeds but `RegQueryValueEx()` fails.

Try this instead:

```
if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, csVersKey, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    char szTemp[257];
    DWORD BufferSize = 256;

    if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "BasePath", NULL, NULL, (BYTE*)szTemp, &BufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        szTemp[BufferSize] = '\0';
        m_reqPath = szTemp;
        ...
    }

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

To avoid this issue altogether, use [`RegGetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868.aspx) instead, which deals with the null terminator for you:

```
char szTemp[257];
DWORD BufferSize = sizeof(szTemp);

if (RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, csVersKey, "BasePath", RRF_RT_REG_SZ | RRF_RT_REG_MULTI_SZ | RRF_RT_REG_EXPAND_SZ, NULL, szTemp, &BufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    m_reqPath = szTemp;
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, csVersKey, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    char szTemp[257];
    DWORD BufferSize = sizeof(szTemp);

    if (RegGetValue(hKey, NULL, "BasePath", RRF_RT_REG_SZ | RRF_RT_REG_MULTI_SZ | RRF_RT_REG_EXPAND_SZ, NULL, szTemp, &BufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        m_reqPath = szTemp;
        ...
    }

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the original `RegSetValueEx()` call was omitting the null terminator. That is not uncommon, which is why Microsoft created `RegGetValue()` to deal with that issue so programmers would not have to worry about it anymore.

Comment: Thanks Remy.I have updated my post. I too had noticed, after Michael Walz's comment that the RegSetValueEx was being passed the wrong byte count. I feel this should be correct [m_reqLeicaPath.GetLength() + 1]. The only problem with all this is that this is an INTERMITTENT bug. This does not happen consistently. I have never been able to reproduce the issue anywhere. RegGetValue seems promising. I had a look at it. This app is someone else's responsibility and i will have to put a strong  case so as to force them to make a change.

Answer (score 0):

In some code pages the currency symbol is the same byte value in ASCII as the backslash. If you're using Unicode functions this shouldn't be an issue though.

See http://www.siao2.com/2005/09/17/469941.aspx for more information.

Comment: Installshield Engine is Unicode compliant. I see a foreign character _appended_ to the backslash. The backslash is not replaced by the character.